# Present UIViewController modally within a UIViewController that does not cover full screen

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, modalviewcontroller, presentmodalviewcontroller

Basically once I dismissed the modal view, my customized UIToolbar no longer clickable.

Here is my design:

- a customized UIToolbar at the bottom of the screen
- top part of the screen is associated with a container view controller
  [note] I added the top two items above into a root view controller and assigned to UIWinow's root view controller. The container view can be changed whenever toolbar items are clicked.
- then, each toolbar item associated with a UINavigationController so that it's navigable.
- within a UIViewController of a navigation, I present a view modally. The modal view does NOT cover the full screen as a result of the entire design...
- after i dismiss the modal view, the UIToolbar items are no longer clickable.

I think the 'bug' is resided in where i presented the modal view, so I also tried to present modal view using root view controller, then there is also other issues...

maybe someone has more insight on this, that will be really appreciated :)

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Try releasing the `modalViewController` as soon as its no longer needed. If you are using ARC, set it to `nil`. Allocate a new one when a modalView is needed.

Comment: thanks a lot. I am doing the dismiss call within a method of the modal Controller's implementation; the method is invoked when a button on the modal view is clicked. Without using a delegate to call from parent, i am not able to set the modalViewController to nil.

Comment: I fixed it finally. On dismissing the modal view controller, obtaining the root controller from AppDelegate, then obtain the navigation controller and show the nav bar since it was hidden.